# Mouse wheel works bad in some programs?

Tags: mouse, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I have Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000 connected to USB dongle by radio, along with Microsoft's keyboard, and USB dongle is connected to KVM into "keyboard" socket.

I have mouse wheel working badly in some applications, for example in Adobe Help system which probably written in Air.

The situation is follows: if I rotate a wheel slowly, scrolling doesn't occur at all. If I rotate quickly it occurs. So in everyday work it feels like window reacts lazily, sometimes skipping my scroll commands.

Comment: It could be a case of your setup (possibly due to latency?) causing some of the scroll events (packets?) to be dropped, so you need to scroll a lot more/faster to ensure that at least some of them get through. But then that should affect all programs equally. Are you sure it only happens in some programs and not all, and is there anything in common between the problem programs?

Comment: What have you tried already? If you omit the KVM does the scrolling work as expected?  Have you tried relocating the USB receiver?